# Macro works fine copting data until it finds duplicate. I want it to copy the duplicate

Tags: excel, vba

This macro copies certain cells from sheet `Source_1` to sheet Table if it finds a value in column A in sheet Table matching column A in sheet `Source_1`. Problem is that if value is duplicate in column A of sheet `Source_1`. It copies the cells of the first occurrence from sheet `Source_1` again and again. I would like it to copy the different occurrences (rows).

```
Sub RechercheValeursFSI_1()

    Dim FeSource As Worksheet
    Dim FeDest As Worksheet
    Dim PlgSource As Range
    Dim PlgDest As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim Ligne As Long
    Set FeSource = Worksheets("SOURCE_1")
    Set FeDest = Worksheets("Table")
    With FeSource
        Set PlgSource = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With FeDest
        Set PlgDest = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    For Each Cel In PlgDest
        On Error Resume Next
        Ligne = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cel.Value, PlgSource, 0) + 1
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Cel.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 5).Value = FeSource.Cells(Ligne, 1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 5).Value
        End If
    Next Cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub RechercheValeursFSI_1()

    'Declarations.
    Dim FeSource As Worksheet
    Dim FeDest As Worksheet
    Dim PlgSource As Range
    Dim PlgDest As Range
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim Ligne As Long
    Dim IntCompteur As Integer
    
    'Setting variables.
    Set FeSource = Worksheets("SOURCE_1")
    Set FeDest = Worksheets("Table")
    With FeSource
        Set PlgSource = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With FeDest
        Set PlgDest = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    'Covering the whole PlgDest.
    For Each Cel In PlgDest
        On Error Resume Next
        
        'Setting Ligne for each occurence the code already met.
        IntCompteur = 0
        Ligne = 0
        Do Until IntCompteur >= Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(FeDest.Range(FeDest.Cells(1, 1), Cel), Cel.Value)
            Ligne = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cel.Value, PlgSource.Resize(PlgSource.Rows.Count - Ligne + 1).Offset(Ligne - 1, 0), 0) + Ligne
            IntCompteur = IntCompteur + 1
        Loop
        
        'Copy-pasting the values.
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Cel.Offset(, 4).Resize(, 5).Value = FeSource.Cells(Ligne, 1).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 5).Value
        End If
        
    Next Cel
    
End Sub
```

I've added a integer variable (IntCompteur) to run a Do-Loop cycle. The cycle repeats itself according to the number of previous occurence of the value in Cel in the already covered cells. It sets the Ligne value until it gets to the wanted cell. It achieves it basically resizing the range within the match function searched for the given value.